# Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules: need newData's child that is dynamically created and wildcard $ doesnt work

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I only want to be able to add that user(object) to my "**Entry**" node if the **name** field exist in the "**AllowedEntry**" node.

```
-AllowedEntry
            |--ABC
            |     |--name: "ABC"
            |     |--age: 20
            |--LMN
            |     |--name: "LMN"
            |     |--age: 55
            |--XYZ
                  |--name: "XYZ"
                  |--age: 88
            
            
-Entry
      |--ABC
             |--name:"ABC"
             |--age:20
             |--dept:"Code"
             |--isAdmin:false
```

Over here the **ABC record at Entry** is possible because the name field value of ABC(ie "ABC") exists under **AllowedEntry**

but the below must fail

```
-Entry
      |--PQR
           |--name:"PQR"
           |--age:52
           |--dept:"dsfg"
           |--isAdmin:true
```

because this PQR objects name("PQR") doesnt exist under the node of **AllowedEntry**

This is what I have tried from my end but been unsuccessful. the Reading permission has been set successfully... we dont need that

```js
"Entry": {
  "$id": {
    ".write": "root.child('AllowedEntry/'+ newData.child('$id').child('name').val() ).exists()",
  }
}
```

The above doesnt work because a wildcard '$id' doesnt work with newData.child()

And if i do away with the '$id' we are not able to access the child node in the Json eg.

```js
"Entry": {
  ".write": "root.child('AllowedEntry/'+ newData.child(**???**).child('name').val() ).exists()",
}
```

I wouldnt know what to enter in the **???** since the Json that comes flying into our DB looks like this

```js
{
  "ABC": {
    "name": "ABC",
    "age": 20,
    "dept": "Code",
    "isAdmin": true 
  }
}
```

You see Json with only

```js
  {
     "name": "ABC",
     "age": 20,
     "dept": "Code",
     "isAdmin": true 
  }
```

would work perfectly with `".write": "root.child('AllowedEntry/'+ newData.child('name').val() ).exists()"`

but then there would be only one reord in the ENTRY node.

Adding an image to show you the outputs, the Json and the data[image]

Comment: In your JSON is the **key** of the entries under `AllowedEntry` always the same as the value of the `name` property.

Comment: Updated the question with an image... and YES... I did make my JSON key the same as the name property ... because I thought it would ease the complication of the rule.

Comment: It wouldn't just ease it, without that key it simply wouldn't be possible as security rules cannot search across data (that wouldn't scale). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fragment in your first rules snippet is wrong:

```
newData.child('$id').child('name')
```

The `'$id'` in there is just a literal string, rather than the value of the `$id` capture variable. To use the latter:

```
newData.child($id).child('name')
```

---

Also, there is no need for string concatenation and this is more readable:

```
"root.child('AllowedEntry').child(newData.child($id).child('name').val()).exists()"
```

---

In your screenshot I noticed that you:

1. Define the rules on the `$id` node,
2. Then use `newData.child('$id').child('name').val()` in your condition.

`newData` refers to the new data on the node where it is used. So this code now looks for a node named `$id` under the `$id` node, which exist. You probably want `newData.child('name').val()`.

Comment: It doesnt work. Im sorry I had caught this mistake, but it still doesnt work. for some reason if I ever introduce $id to the newData.child()... it doesnt work. I have tried this on the Rules Playground loads of times, but keeps failing. Could you double check this please?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is really hard to help with. What I pointed out is a mistake in the question you posted. There may be more mistakes, but this is definitely going to keep it from working.

Comment: Updated the answer with an image so you could get a better understanding of whats failing

Comment: Can you try writing to `/Entry/XYZ` instead?

Comment: Yes that works... But you see, How would you know that the node the client side is going to create via that JSON is going to be XYZ?... XYZ only comes into existence after the client fires that JSON whose key is "XYZ". I've tried it even from the front end .. it fails!?! Any ideas... pls let me know... i'll keep trying it at my end and reverting back to you.

Comment: Yeah, the readability is true... but I just cant understand why its not working. Does this mean our security rules cant do a scenario like this?

Comment: So just following up... if it cant be answered should I just accept that the Firebase security rules cant solve something like this ? A dynamically generated Key cant be identified by a $ newData's wildcard???

Comment: I added another update.

Comment: I have to be honest - I read your answer 5 times, and really thought you had lost it! But wow.. just amazing, you cracked it. It felt twisted but is true. I will update my answer. Thanks again.